Daughter runs away with her mother's boyfriend's son
I'm looking for a movie in which a little girl discovers that her mother is cheating on her father and burns down the mother along with her ''boyfriend''. Then the little girl runs away from home with a boy. That particular boy is her mother's boyfriend's son!
The movie, if I remember correctly, was released around 2006-2012. It also includes a caravan... I have not seen the movie, I am merely looking for its name to watch it, thus I don't know details about how the actors look like. I know that possibly they are white and the main characters (the little girl and the boy I mentioned) are kids/teenagers during the movie.

Is the movie in English or another language? Is it US-based, or elsewhere? Are the main characters white/asian/etc? Fat? Redhead? Aproximate age? Any details you can think of to close down the list of possible answers would be appreciated.

I edited my question, take a look if u will

Sounds like The Burning Plain from 2008.

The story starts some time during the mid-1990s in a small town near Las Cruces, New Mexico (close to the border with Mexico), where we are introduced to Gina (Kim Basinger), a wife and mother to four children. Gina is having an affair with a local man named Nick Martinez (Joaquim de Almeida), who also has a family of his own; but, unbeknownst to the two, Gina's teenage daughter Mariana (Jennifer Lawrence) finds out about their love affair. Mariana follows her mother to Nick's trailer. Knowing the two are inside; and, in an effort to make them end their affair, she disconnects the gas pipe leading into the trailer and sets it on fire. The flames eventually reach a gas tank, which explodes, consuming the entire trailer and claiming Nick's and Gina's lives, although Mariana had no intention of killing either of them. After their funeral, Mariana and Nick's teenage son, Santiago (JD Pardo), slowly begin to develop a relationship of their own. Mariana soon becomes aware that she is pregnant with Santiago's daughter. The two flee to Mexico amid disapproval from their families and decide to have the baby there; but, after she gives birth to their daughter, Mariana abandons her family and changes her name to Sylvia.

Written by Guillermo Arriaga, who wrote Amores Perros, 21 Grams and Babel. Here's the trailer:



